# Hotmail.com not working, throws error on desktop

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, email, microsoft-edge, hotmail

All of a sudden, I am no longer able to access my browser-based Hotmail.com inbox on desktop.

- Issue persists across browsers: Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.
- Tried updating the browsers, clearing history, updating and restarting my computer.
- Email is still working on mobile iOS.

Attached is a screenshot of the error below:

[image: Hotmail.com error message]

**Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: This is a server-side error. There is nothing you can do, except maybe contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: @DanielB shucks :( that's what i thought by looking at the error message initially, but why would there be a server side error that only affects desktop? theyre using diff servers to serve mobile/desktop?

Comment: Yes, this is very common, because mobile devices are typically more restricted concerning resources and internet access.

Comment: @DanielB the other strange thing is tried googling issues with hotmail.com and go no recent hits (quite possibly because i am the last person on earth still using hotmail.com lol). anyways, thanks for the confirmation dan

Comment: @DanielB John's solution actually fixed it o:

Comment: By flushing the DNS cache you may be directed to a different server (load balancing) that is not malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Hotmail - it is purely browser based. You already know it is working (works on IOS).

**(A) Try Microsoft Support.**

If they say the error is on your side, then try resetting TCP/IP and DNS

**(B) TCP/IP DNS Reset:**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

(2) ipconfig /flushdns

(3) restart the computer

Comment: omg it worked. i was convinced it was server-side issue, especially after dan said the same thing. **any idea why this was happening?**

Comment: for some reason i cant find the resetlog.txt in my C drive :/

Comment: If you followed the reset line, the log should be in the root directory of C:

Comment: i did indeed, but i dont see it there and my hidden files are turned on too. is this indicative of something else possibly gone wrong? or perhaps only a typo when i exe the cmd? any idea why this happened so perhaps i can prevent/fix it in the future?

Comment: Possible.  Try running DISM / SFC  .......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: This has been a problem for outlook.com today. several of my contractors are having the same issue. my first guess is that the issue was resolved by MS and this didn't actually do anything but kill a few minutes before the service came back up.

Comment: @FrankThomas interesting! yeah, mine didnt come back automatically and was like this for at least an hour or 2 before i executed johns solution

Comment: It was (as noted here) that clearing DNS helped a lot.